# TypeError: MinMaxScaler does not support sparse input. Consider using MaxAbsScaler instead

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to scale a sparse array.:

```
X_rest_features_train = np.array(X_rest_features_train, dtype=float)
X_rest_features_train = csr_matrix(X_rest_features_train)
X_rest_features_test = np.array(X_rest_features_test, dtype=float)
X_rest_features_test = csr_matrix(X_rest_features_test) 

X_train = hstack([X_text_train, X_rest_features_train])
X_test = hstack([X_text_test, X_rest_features_test])


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)


sgd_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, I receive this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-83abc57d52ab> in <module>
     92 
     93     scaler = MinMaxScaler()
---> 94     X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
     95     X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
     96 

...

TypeError: MinMaxScaler does not support sparse input. Consider using MaxAbsScaler instead.
```

I am using:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
# 0.23.1
```

Unless I am missing something, in the sklearn documentation it is said that sparse arrays are supported though:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html

Am I missing something?

If not then is `MaxAbsScaler` equally good?

P.S.

I have tested `MaxAbsScaler` and it looks to work well so I am good with that too.
But I am still wondering a bit about the `MaxAbsScaler`.

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using? (Your link is for version 0.23, whereas the docs for version 0.22 at https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html?highlight=minmaxscaler#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.fit_transform don't mention sparse support in MinMaxScaler - this might indicate that it was changed).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, I was using 0.22 but I just upgraded (if I did it right) and as I am mentioning at my post when I do this `print(sklearn.__version__)`, I receive back `0.23.1`. So unless I am doing something wrong, still sparse arrays are not supported despite what it is mentioned at the docs (and for example here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1324)?

Comment: Sorry, I had completely overlooked the print(...) statement. Interestingly, the Github Issue links to a PR, but this PR introduces MaxAbsScaler, so I'd guess that you indeed have to use that one (disclaimer: I've never used scikit-learn, so take everything I'm saying with a large grain of salt)

Comment: No worries @FrankSchmitt ;)

Comment: Any thoughts on this @AndreasMueller? :)